# Robotframework test case does not work even if it matches with my regex

Tags: robotframework, embedded-linux

I want my test case to PASS in both conditions with different messages

in my test case code below, I want it to pass with a message `The BaseOS release version is matched!` if my regex matches. If it does not match I still want it to pass with a different test message which is `Developer Build, Skipping the Version Check`

```
*** Test Cases ***
The BaseOS version must match the pattern
        ${env_var_type}=    Set variable    ""
        Pass Execution If  '${env_var_type}' == ""  Developer Build, Skipping the Version Check
        Set test message  Developer Build, Skipping the Version Check
            ${output}=  Get File   /etc/my-release
            Pass Execution If  '${output}' Should Match Regexp    (^RH\\d.\\dv\\d.\\d_x86)
            Set test message  The BaseOS release version is matched!
```

Right now I get an error

```
Evaluating expression ''RH8.4v0.3_x86
' Should Match Regexp' failed: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<string>, line 1)
```

Can you please tell me what did I miss?

Comment: You show a lot of keywords definitions but they are not used, and the releavnt keyword is in a Library. You condition comes from `${rc}   ${env_var_type}=        Run and Return RC And output     echo $BASEOS_BUILDTYPE`  so you should confirm if it returns the expected value.

Comment: @Helio Actually my confusion is I do not know how to combine and check my regex in my condition. I have more test cases than I show here and the keywords you see are related with them

Comment: I don't know this keyword: `Run and Return RC And output` and your ReEx passed because it is reached. I can't say more than this. You should create a sample test case with mocked data to verify your keywords.

Comment: @Helio What if we forget that keyword and do not use it? I can print Developer Build, Skipping the Version Check if my regex doesn't match and that is all. Am I still missing some point?

Comment: You should rephrase your question, because there is too much code not relevant to it. In my view, this is True because you can reach the other steps: `Should Match Regexp    ${output}       (^RH\\d.\\dv\\d.\\d_x86)`

Comment: @Helio I rephreased my question. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: The error you get is due to missing spaces after condition.

Comment: I’m not sure that I understand you. Do I need a blank line between my conditions? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: This line is missing a space: or a newline before Should:  `Pass Execution If  '${output}' Should Match Regexp    (^RH\\d.\\dv\\d.\\d_x86)`
Can you create an runnable example?